# "For" loop - assign value to properties using PropertyInfo

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a quick interview form using a C# Console application.

The form is consisted from questions (that are read from text file using StreamReader) and from answers, that I want to get using Console.ReadLine().

Every answer should be saved into the property defined in the PotentialEmployee class. I do not want to write again same piece of code, so what came to my mind is to do a for loop.

In the for loop, I will always first load a question from StreamReader and then I want to assign an answer to a properties, that are defined in PropertyInfo and every answer should be assigned to another property (like Name, BirthDate, etc.), so I made an index variable.

But sadly, the program is not working properly, as it does not save the informations to the properties.

```
PotentialEmployee pe = new PotentialEmployee();
PropertyInfo[] pi = pe.GetType().GetProperties();

using (StreamReader InterviewQuestions = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    for (int particularQuestion = 0; particularQuestion < TotalLines(filePath); 
         particularQuestion++)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(InterviewQuestions.ReadLine());
        pi[index].SetValue(pe, Console.ReadLine(), null);
        index++;
    }
}
```

So it should look like this:

1) What is your name?

```
Name = Console.ReadLine()
```

2) When you were born?

```
BirthDate = Console.ReadLine()
```

etc. Could you please help me solve this problem? Thank you!

EDIT: Already spotted my stupid mistake, that index will always be zero. Anyway, I am going to rewrite this to Dictionary, as suggested. Thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: Why do you need reflection for this?

Comment: And how are you, or the code, meant to know that e.g. question 1 was "What is your name?" versus "When you were born?". It seems like the property to access should be tied to the specific question, but how are you proposing that such a link exist?

Comment: @vc74 Because I wanted to loop through the properties and assign the value using for loop. Or do you think there is better solution, how to assign a values to the properties, when I do not want to write (name of property) = Console.ReadLine() over and over again?

Comment: I think they should be tied in a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - the questions are written in the text file. I am reading from a text file using StreamReader class.

Comment: So someone edits the text file and swaps the first two questions. Are you saying we should now store the answer to "When you were born?" in the `Name` property and "What is your name?" in the `BirthDate` property?

Comment: @Unnamed - could you please elaborate more further? How should I rewrite this code to Dictionary please?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to achieve a similar result, such as using a Dictionary to store user answers (you could also store a more complex structure to keep track of the corresponding question for a particular answer) and it strictly depends on how you want to implement this feature. Reflection shouldn't be your choice for a lot of different reasons.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - yes, I realize now that this is bad practice. Thank you. How should I make this program better please?

Comment: @deez4h thanks for your answer. What should I put as a TKey and TValue in Dictionary? I have multiple types of properties in my class - (Name = string, BirthDate = DateTime, etc.), so I am not really sure.

Comment: index will always be 0

Comment: @StormMuller - yes, I already see my stupid mistake :D, anyway I am going to rewrite this program to Dictionary, as suggested here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to achieve the above would be to store each question as a `Key` and each answer as a `Value` in a `Dictionary`, as suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever. This will give you a structure that records each Question and Response and allow you to iterate through them using the Question as an identifier.

Below is a simple suggestion of how you could add a dictionary to your `PotentialEmployee` class and then use the console to record the results

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PotentialEmployee pe = new PotentialEmployee();

    using (StreamReader InterviewQuestions = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\Questions.txt"))
    {
        string question;
        while ((question = InterviewQuestions.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(question);
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            pe.Responses.Add(question, response);
        }
    }

    // The following will then go through your results and print them to the console to     
    // demonstrate how to access the dictionary

    Console.WriteLine("Results:");

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in pe.Responses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
    }
}

...

class PotentialEmployee
{
    // Add a dictionary to your object properties
    public Dictionary<string, string> Responses { get; set; }
    ...

    public PotentialEmployee()
    {
        // Make sure you initialize the Dictionary in the Constructor
        Responses = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will rewrite this program :)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that sequence of questions in the file and properties against which you want to store the answer should have same sequence.

this is working for me

```
PotentialEmployee pe = new PotentialEmployee();
PropertyInfo[] pi = pe.GetType().GetProperties();
string filePath = "D:\\Questions.txt";
using (StreamReader InterviewQuestions = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    for (int particularQuestion = 0; particularQuestion < TotalLines(filePath);
         particularQuestion++)
    {                    
        Console.WriteLine(InterviewQuestions.ReadLine());
        pi[particularQuestion].SetValue(pe, Console.ReadLine(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I made a stupid mistake, as my index will always be zero :)